# Flattening a Nested List in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm doing [problem 7](https://ocaml.org/problems?difficulty_level=All#7) of the OCaml exercises. It basically asks given a nested list as defined:

> ```ml
> type 'a node =
>   | One of 'a 
>   | Many of 'a node list
> ```

Write a function function `flatten` that flattens it:

> ```ml
> assert (
>   flatten [ One "a"; Many [ One "b"; Many [ One "c"; One "d" ]; One "e" ] ]
>   = [ "a"; "b"; "c"; "d"; "e" ])
> ```

The solution provided by the website is as follows:

> ```ml
> let flatten list =
>   let rec aux acc = function
>     | [] -> acc
>     | One x :: t -> aux (x :: acc) t
>     | Many l :: t -> aux (aux acc l) t
>   in
>   List.rev (aux [] list)
> ;;
> ```

I'm wondering why they do `x :: acc` and then reverse the list instead of `acc @ [x]` which would avoid the need to reverse the list at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How does `@` work? Well, let's define it.

```
let rec (@) lst1 lst2 =
  match lst1 with 
  | [] -> lst2
  | x::xs -> x :: (xs @ lst2)
```

So, in order to append one list to another, we have to iterate over *all of the first list*. If we do this within a loop, as that first list gets longer, it takes longer to get to the end of it. In big-O notation, this has O(n^2) or "quadratic" performance. Fine for small sample sizes, but prohibitive for large sample sizes.

However, `::` occurs in *constant* time. It doesn't matter how big the list is, it will always take the same amount of time to cons a value onto the front of it. If we do that in a loop, we get O(n) or "linear" performance.

Reversing a list also works in linear time. Is it costly to run *two* linear time operations? Certainly more so that running *one*, but consider two times n vs. n squared:

| n | 2n | n^2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | 6 | 8 |
| 4 | 8 | 16 |
| 100 | 200 | 10,000 |
| 10,000 | 20,000 | 100,000,000 |
| 1,000,000 | 2,000,000 | 1,000,000,000,000 |

An additional note: the implementation of `flatten` shown by the OP which utilizes `::` is not tail-recursive. The following would be:

```
let flatten lst =
  let rec aux lst to_process acc =
    match lst, to_process with
    | [], [] -> acc
    | [], _ -> aux to_process [] acc
    | (One v)::xs, _ -> aux xs to_process (v :: acc)
    | (Many lst')::xs, _ -> aux lst' (xs @ to_process) acc
  in
  List.rev @@ aux lst [] []
```

Following the evaluation of your sample data:

```
flatten [One "a"; Many [One "b"; Many [One "c"; One "d"]; One "e"]]
aux [One "a"; Many [One "b"; Many [One "c"; One "d"]; One "e"]] []        []
aux [Many [One "b"; Many [One "c"; One "d"]; One "e"]]          []        ["a"]
aux [One "b"; Many [ One "c"; One "d" ]; One "e" ]              []        ["a"]
aux [Many [ One "c"; One "d"]; One "e"]                         []        ["b"; "a"]
aux [One "c"; One "d"]                                          [One "e"] ["b"; "a"]
aux [One "d"]                                                   [One "e"] ["c"; "b"; "a"]
aux [One "e"]                                                   []        ["d"; "c"; "b"; "a"]
aux []                                                          []        ["e"; "d"; "c"; "b"; "a"]
List.rev ["e"; "d"; "c"; "b"; "a"]
["a"; "b"; "c"; "d"; "e"]
```